# ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

now I did some tutorials about MoveIt and have met some errors. I followed the instructions from https://moveit.ros.org/install/source/ and when I run 'rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro ${ROS_DISTRO}', the error was like:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
moveit_core: No definition of [libfcl-dev] for OS version []
moveit_ros_perception: No definition of [eigen] for OS version []
rviz_visual_tools: No definition of [libogre-dev] for OS version []
moveit_tutorials: No definition of [eigen] for OS version []
moveit_servo: No definition of [rosparam_shortcuts] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_occupancy_map_monitor: No definition of [eigen] for OS version []
geometric_shapes: No definition of [eigen] for OS version []
moveit_ros_planning: No definition of [eigen] for OS version []
pilz_industrial_motion_planner: No definition of [code_coverage] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_manipulation: No definition of [eigen] for OS version []
moveit_kinematics: No definition of [eigen] for OS version []
moveit_ros_visualization: No definition of [libogre-dev] for OS version []
moveit_resources_prbt_support: No definition of [code_coverage] for OS [debian]
moveit_ros_planning_interface: No definition of [eigen] for OS version []
moveit_setup_assistant: No definition of [yaml-cpp] for OS version []
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380764/error:-the-following-packages/stacks-could-not-have-their-rosdep-keys-resolved-to-system-dependencies:/) by [ruiaisun](https://answers.ros.org/users/76435/ruiaisun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-22**:
To get it out of the way: do you absolutely *need* to build MoveIt from sources?

**Comment by [ruiaisun](https://answers.ros.org/users/76435/ruiaisun/) on 2021-06-22**:
Yes. To use some motion planners. This problem is solved! I just remove miniconda. Thank you for asking.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-22**:
This does not seem like it's a duplicate question.

Please also post your solution as an answer below and then accept your own answer.

That way it's clear you've solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I remove the miniconda and than the problem is gone.

---

Originally posted by [ruiaisun](https://answers.ros.org/users/76435/ruiaisun/) with karma: 16 on 2022-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0